# Print a PDF file with MFC

Tags: c++, pdf, printing, mfc

In my app `(MFC, C++)` I have a button that creates a `PDF` file in a path.
Now I want to create another button that will print the pdf starting from the path and choosing some option like orientation and number of copies... but I'm not able to do that...

I saw that `CPrintDialog` shows the default dialog of the printer but I'm not able to attach the PDF file using the path.

I saw also the

```
ShellExecute(NULL, L"print", L"C:\\Documents\\1.pdf", NULL, NULL, SW_SHOWNORMAL);
```

that works but in this way I cannot choose any parameter...

How I can use the `CPrintDialog` to print an existing PDF that is in a path?

Answer (score -2, accepted):

I have solved with a workaround. Instead of use the ShellExecute, I draw all the thing that I want to print using a `CDC` object attached to the hDC of a `CPrintDialog` class. Rember to manage the size of the draw depending on printer DPI like [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/943279/printed-cdc-appears-tiny-on-paper).

A snippet only to have an idea:

```
    CPrintDialog printDialog(FALSE);

    printDialog.GetDefaults();

    printDialog.m_pd.Flags &= ~PD_RETURNDEFAULT;

    DEVMODE* pDevMode = printDialog.GetDevMode();
    pDevMode->dmFields = DM_ORIENTATION | DM_PAPERSIZE | DM_PRINTQUALITY ;
    pDevMode->dmOrientation = DMORIENT_LANDSCAPE;
    pDevMode->dmPaperSize = DMPAPER_A4;
    ::GlobalUnlock(printDialog.m_pd.hDevMode);

   if (printDialog.DoModal() == IDOK)
   {
       CDC* pDC = new CDC;
       pDC->Attach(printDialog.m_pd.hDC);
       pDCPDF->StartDoc(_T(""));
       pDCPDF->StartPage();
       // ...
       //draw what you want 
       // ...
       pDCPDF->EndPage();
       pDCPDF->EndDoc(); //this starts the printer          
       pDCPDF->DeleteDC();
   }
```

Hope to reach soon the reputation of 15 to vote the answer of other questions.
Thanks to Andrew Komiagin answers.

Comment: You asked about printing PDF, but this has nothing to do with PDF

Comment: Well my target was print a PDF, the same of the first snippet `1.pdf`, but I achieve the same result in another way that is probably better.

Answer (score 2):

You have to use `ShellExecuteEx` and verb *printto* to get more control over printing:

```
      SHELLEXECUTEINFO ShellInfo;
      ZeroMemory(&ShellInfo, sizeof(SHELLEXECUTEINFO));
      ShellInfo.cbSize = sizeof(SHELLEXECUTEINFO);
      ShellInfo.lpVerb = L"printto";
      ShellInfo.lpFile = L"C:\\Documents\\1.pdf";
      ShellInfo.lpParameters = szPrinter;
      ShellInfo.nShow = SW_SHOWNORMAL;
      ShellInfo.fMask = SEE_MASK_FLAG_DDEWAIT | SEE_MASK_NOCLOSEPROCESS;
      if(::ShellExecuteEx(&ShellInfo))
      {
         if((int)ShellInfo.hInstApp > 32)
         {
            if(ShellInfo.hProcess != NULL)
            {
               DWORD dwExitCode = STILL_ACTIVE;
               while(dwExitCode == STILL_ACTIVE)
               {
                  if(!::GetExitCodeProcess(ShellInfo.hProcess, &dwExitCode))
                  {
                     dwExitCode = 0;
                  }
               }
               ::CloseHandle(ShellInfo.hProcess);
            }
         }
      }
```

To get the printer name:

```
CPrintDialog dlg(TRUE);
if (dlg.DoModal() == IDOK)
{
    CString sPrinterName = dlg.GetDeviceName();
}
```

Comment: Sorry but it's not clear for me.. what is `szPrinter` ?
If I use the line 
`ShellExecute(NULL, L"printto", L"C:\\Documents\\1.pdf", NULL, NULL, SW_SHOWNORMAL);` nothing changed...

Comment: `szPrinter` is your target printer identified by name

Comment: How I can take that name? How the user can choose that printer options, through CPrintDialog?

Comment: I've updated the answer to show you how to get the printer name

Comment: Thank you. I'm working on your snippet... I will write soon

Comment: Now I get the correct name of my printer; your code works but only if the default printer is the same choosed in the PrinterDialog; if I change the printer, I can see the correct in line `ShellInfo.lpParameters = szPrinter;` but the printer doesn't start. Same when I change some parameters like the number of copy, the paper size and the orientation of sheet... but I think for this last three I need to find a way to catch this parameter from the PrinterDialog e pass they to the ShelleExecute (like the printer name)...